# When a polynomial in two variables of (total) degree three is irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14076/irreducibility-of-polynomials-in-two-variables) asks for sufficient criteria for a polynomial in two variables over a field, to be irreducible.

Let $u= Ax^3+Bx^2y+Cxy^2+Dy^3+ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f \in k[x,y]$,
for some field $k$ (further assume that $k=\mathbb{C}$, if this helps).

> Assume that $u$ is irreducible; is it possible to find all the forms of such $u$?

I only know how to show that, after a change of variables, we can obtain $B=0$; this is true in general, regardless of irreducibility (a change of variables does not change irreducibility;
in other words, an automorphism of $k[x,y]$ takes an irreducible polynomial to an irreducible polynomial).

**A partial answer:** It follows from one of the answers to the above mentioned question that $s(x)-t(y)$ is irreducible, if the degrees of $s$ and $t$ are coprime.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be the other way around: you can determine all the reducible $u$
by looking at the forms of possible factors. Any $u$ that does not fall into one of those cases is irreducible.

EDIT: To simplify slightly, let's take $A = 1$ and $B=0$ (in a complete solution you'll also have to consider the case $A=0$, but I won't).  A reducible $u$ of degree $3$ must have a factor of degree $1$, let's say $x + p y + q$ (again I'm neglecting the case of factors that depend only on $y$...).
The remainder of $u$ on division by $x + p y + q$ (for the variable $x$) is
$$  \left( -{p}^{3}-Cp+D \right) {y}^{3}+ \left( a{p}^{2}-
3\,{p}^{2}q-Cq-bp+c \right) {y}^{2}+ \left( 2\,apq-3\,p{q}^{2
}-bq-dp+e \right) y+a{q}^{2}-{q}^{3}-dq+f
$$
which must be identically $0$, i.e. the coefficient of each power of $y$ here must be $0$.  This gives us four polynomials in $p, q$ and the coefficients of $u$.  In order for $u$ to have a factor of this form, these polynomials must have a common zero.

Thus $u$ is reducible if there are $p$ and $q$ such that
$$ \eqalign{D &= p^3 + C p\cr
            c &= -a p^2 + 3 p^2 q + C q + b p\cr
            e & = -2apq + 3 pq^2 + bq + dp\cr
            f & = - a q^2 + q^3 + d q\cr} $$

It's possible to eliminate $p$ and $q$ from those polynomials, obtaining polynomials in $C, \ldots, f$, however the results are rather horrendously complicated.

To be somewhat less ambitious, let's fix some of the coefficients, say 
$a=-2,b=-1,c=0,d=1,e=2,f=3$, and ask for what $C$ and $D$ we get a reducible 
$u = x^3 + C x y^2+D y^3-2 x^2-x y+x+2 y+3$.
The equations become
$$ \eqalign{D &= p^3 + C p\cr
            0 &= 2 p^2 + 3 p^2 q + C q - p\cr
            2 & = 4pq + 3 pq^2 - q + p\cr
            3 & = 2 q^2 + q^3 +  q\cr} $$
Using a Groebner basis in Maple, this is equivalent to
$$ \eqalign{44217 D^3+ & 6069 D^2+86 D+3 = 0\cr
       C &= -{\frac {867\,{D}^{2}}{13}}-{\frac {68\,D}{13}}-\frac{1}{13}\cr q&=-{\frac {
88434\,{D}^{2}}{325}}-{\frac {18207\,D}{325}}-{\frac{609}{325}}\cr p&={
\frac {14739\,{D}^{2}}{325}}+{\frac {272\,D}{325}}-\frac{61}{325}}$$

Comment: I like your idea! This way I will only have to 'classify' irreducibles of degree two (which is a simpler task). But for $v=ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f$, I only know the above mentioned sufficient criterion.

Comment: In other words: How to find all irreducibles of degree two?

Comment: Again, reducibles of degree $2$ are products of polynomials of degree $1$.  Anything not  reducible is irreducible.

Comment: How to obtain an explicit form of an irreducible (or reducible, as you suggested) of degree three? I thought there are two kinds of reducibles: product of three degree one polynomials and a product of degree two irreducible and degree one.

Comment: I understand that you suggest to find the form of the degree two irreducible by what it is not (it is not reducible=it is not a product of two degree one).

Comment: So (of course) your idea works ok, though I hoped there exists a more 'direct' way to find the form of an irreducible (like the sufficient criterion about $s(x)-t(y)$).

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations and calculations, which are very helpful to me!